# distribute remain_qty between dist_start & dist_finish

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

**How to distribute remain_qty** **between dist_start & dist_finish** on Line & Stacked Column Chart Visual in Power BI as per excel attached. One limitation here is the **remain_qty not to be distributed on weekend days [Saturdays & Sundays] & on Public Holidays**. I have updated Public Holiday on Sheet 2 of the excel for quick reference. **remain_qty to be distributed in between working days of dist_start & dist_finish only**.

**[excel](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oFSSczQg-VtSdxwYAleqzvey2QcDUPfA/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=111637703513802384395&rtpof=true&sd=true)**

Excel can be used as a source file to develop a solution in Power BI.

[image: Power BI Visual]

The visual above is **currently showing remain_qty on dist_finish date** and **not on the whole duration** between **dist_start & dist_finish**.
If anything you need to start is missing, please comment and I am happy to provide it.

Answer (score 0):

In Power Query you can use the `List.Dates` function to generate a list of dates for each task, and then use `Table.ExpandListColumn` to create one row per task per date, and then allocate the work to each day.  Here's a complete query

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\Users\david\Downloads\excel 2.xlsx"), null, true),
    Sheet1_Sheet = Source{[Item="Sheet1",Kind="Sheet"]}[Data],
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(Sheet1_Sheet, [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Promoted Headers",{"taskrsrc_id", "remain_qty", "dist_start", "dist_finish"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Other Columns", "StartDate", each Date.FromText([dist_start], [Format="dd/MM/yyyy"])),
    #"Duplicated Column" = Table.DuplicateColumn(#"Added Custom", "StartDate", "StartDate - Copy"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Duplicated Column",{"StartDate - Copy", "StartDate"}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Custom", each Date.FromText([dist_start],[Culture="en-GB"])),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom1",{{"Custom", "StartDate"}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Renamed Columns", "EndDate", each Date.FromText([dist_finish],[Culture="en-GB"])),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom2",{"dist_start", "dist_finish"}),
    #"Added Custom4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns1", "Duration", each Duration.Days([EndDate]-[StartDate])+1),
    #"Added Custom3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom4", "Day", each List.Dates([StartDate],[Duration],#duration(1,0,0,0))),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Added Custom3",{"StartDate", "EndDate"}),
    #"Expanded Days" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "Day"),
    #"Added Custom5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Expanded Days", "Custom", each Value.Divide([remain_qty],[Duration])),
    #"Renamed Columns1" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Added Custom5",{{"Custom", "Quantity"}}),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns1",{"remain_qty", "Duration"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns3",{{"Day", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Then you load it into a model like this

[image]

and it's simple to roll the work up to the month grain

[image]

Comment: Hi David, thanks for sending the pbix to me. Few comments on my review of the pbix you've sent. **Visual used** is Stacked Column Chart & **not Line & Stacked Column Chart**. I intend to use Line & Stacked Column Chart.**remain_qty is a whole number & not text** as in your PBIX File. The **Visual above is showing the count of remain_qty & not sum of remain_qty**.

Comment: **Public Holiday & Weekend is not taken into consideration** when remain_qty is distributed between dist_start & dist_finish      **Visual doesn't drill down to days or week,** it shows data only for month. Appreciate your continuous support on this but above points to be fixed. Thanks